# Completely restart Bash

Tags: bash, bashrc, source, bash-profile

Is there a way to completely restart Bash and reload `.bashrc` and `.profile` and the like? I'd like to make sure my changes worked out properly after editing these files.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Have it replace itself with itself.

```
exec bash -l
```

Note that this won't affect things such as the cwd or exported variables.

Comment: Nice, but I'd especially like to do this in order to check and see if my `PATH` is being set as I want or my `PS1`, etc.

Comment: Take out the `exec` and you get a shell that sources the files that you want.  Then just `exit` when you are done checking.

Comment: @TK: Any variables you *assign* will take precedence over the ones left over from the previous shell.

Comment: So this will work for changing my Bash prompt? Ie, it'll reload my bash prompt each time I run it?

Comment: As long as you're setting `$PS1` in bash's startup files, yes.

Comment: On my screen in Firefox, l (the letter ell) and 1 (the numeral one) look similar.  This is bash dash ell, not bash dash one.

Comment: @Elipticalview: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inconsolata

Comment: It would be nice if the answer included what the `-l` does to save time looking it up.

Answer (score 9):

I urgently suggest to log in on a separate window/screen. This way you still have a working session if something goes wrong with your changes to startup files. Also you are sure to have a clean environment.

Reason: I saw too many people locking themselves out of a system because of a simple typo in their .profile (or such).

Comment: +10, a clean shell where you can change edits is essential.

Comment: I'm in a DE, so it shouldn't be so bad, Bauhaus yes, be careful.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is simply to read the modified files again, you don't have to restart it. You can simply source it.

```
source filename
```

or

```
. filename # notice the dot
```

Note that this won't give you a "clean state" in a sense that it won't unset any set variables or defined functions...

Answer (score 2):

```
su -l yourOwnUserName
```

Will open a fresh shell for `yourOwnUserName` user with all the settings re-loaded. This is shell-independent, as it refers to system settings, not your specific shell. It also loads some system-wide settings that `bash -l` does not (like user groups).

Comment: important note: "a fresh shell" here means a shell within your existing shell, so you are only nesting shells, not replacing your original one. The accepted answer does that properly.