# Does "exec bash -l" work from within a script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

As a follow-up question to the answer proposed in [Completely restart Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22721/completely-restart-bash) -- I'm wondering if this works from within a shell script?

This is for a setup script for new machines.
What I'm doing is replacing a few standard commands with my own variants (e.g. a 'service' variant that provides proper feedback on CentOS 7 instead of a redirect message with no further output) and I'm doing that from a setup.sh script in `bash`. These replacements are copied to `/usr/local/sbin/` but won't take effect until the shell is restarted. I'm planning to do that with: `exec bash -l` as suggested, but does this work from within a shell script?

Comment: It won't replace the parent shell, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `hash -r` will cause the current shell to forget about any cached paths to commands and try to find them again in `$PATH`. If you want to let an unrelated shell do that, you will need its collaboration (eg. have it do a `trap 'hash -r' USR1` and kill it with `kill -USR1`).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. the shell script copies several command files into `/usr/local/sbin` but the existing shell won't pick that up unless the connection is cycled/the shell is restarted. interactively, `exec bash -l` replaces the current bash with a new one, but can that be done as part of a script without interrupting the execution of that script?

Comment: The shell *will* pick that up if you do a `hash -r`. No need for `exec bash -l` (I don't see why you should do that, ever, you can also simply `. ~/profile` if you have updated it). And you cannot force a shell to do an `exec ...` more than you can force it to do a `hash -r` (that are ways, like attaching to it with a debugger, or faking it input with `ioctl(TIOCSTI)`, but they're very slippery and frankly, not worth it). Notice that I'm not telling anything about breaking users' expectations -- most users will NOT appreciate having their shell restarted and all its state wiped off.

Comment: @Mark `exec bash -l` replaces the current bash with a new one, sure, but the current bash is the one started to executed the script, *not the one that you executed the script from*

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question thanks to @mosvy: 
The solution is to use `hash -r` instead of restarting the shell to pick up changed system commands.